# Grouping in Elastic Search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, elasticsearch, nest

I have a problem with doing grouping operation in elastcicSearch.

Actually, I have 3 fields in my document. that is as under:

```
Id Type  Year
```

Now I want to do grouping on ExceptionType and Year and count it in "ResultCount".

I tried this one but it is not working:

```
.Aggregations(a => a
            .ValueCount("ResultCount", c => c
                .Field(p => p.Id)
                .Field(p=> p.Year)
            ))
             .Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms("Type", st => st
                    .Field(o => o.Type)
                    .Size(10))).Size(5)
             .Aggregations(aa => aa
                    .Max("Year", m =>  m
                        .Field(o => o.Year)
                    ))
           );
```

Please give a solution for this problem as soon as possible. thank you.

Comment: what are you getting, in exception?

Comment: One exception is solved by me but,
Actually, I didn't  get any output and i also don't have any idea about how to display that data or watch data data.

Comment: Value Count aggregation works on a single field. If you need to count on a  composite of fields, you could either use terms sub-aggregations or use a script to build a composite key for value count.

Answer (score 0):

Here I will try to help. There is no such thing as group in elastic only terms and sub aggregations. If you want the count of error types by year you can do it like so:

```
  var response = db.Search<Error>(s => 
                s.Size(0)
                .Aggregations(aggs1 => aggs1.Terms("level1",
                        l1 =>l1.Field(f => f.Type)
                               .Aggregations(aggs2 => aggs2.Terms("leve2", t=> t.Field(f=>f.Year))))));

           foreach (var l1 in response.Aggs.Terms("level1").Buckets)
           {
               foreach (var l2 in l1.Terms("leve2").Buckets)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Type:{0}, Year:{1}, Count:{2}", l1.Key, l2.Key, l2.DocCount);
               }
           }
```

But keep in mind that this will only work as you except for a non-analysed or keyword fields if you want terms for dates you can use something like date_histogram aggregation. 
If you index mapping looks like this

```
  {
         "properties": {
            "type": {
               "type": "keyword"
            },
            "year": {
               "type": "long"
            }
         }
  }
```

You will get the number of items per error type per year 
You can do other types of aggregations as well in the nested aggregation 
NOTE: The terms aggregation is approximated so don't be surprised if you don't get exact values.